# Programmatically change cursor speed in windows

Tags: c#, windows-7, mouse-cursor

Since getting a satisfactory answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) is very difficult, I want to rephrase [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/124426/mouse-and-touchpad-move-at-different-speeds) and ask:

Is there any way to programmatically detect a mouse was plugged in the usb port, and change the cursor speed in windows (perhaps through an API)?

I'd like to use C#, but I'm open to any language that can run on a windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the detection but you can use P/Invoke to the [SystemParametersInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/systemparametersinfo.html)  api using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, String pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);
```

with the uiAction as ([SPI_SETMOUSESPEED](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=SPI&namespace=[All])) = 0x0071

Comment: Great, now I only need the other part. Thanks.

Comment: Does http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/740363-need-detect-insertion-removal-usb-drive help?