# Synchronising trackbar movements with cursor speed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent

I have a trackbar on Windows form. I want to synchronise the trackbar movement with Cursor speed in real-time such that as the trackbar value increases/decreases, so does the relative cursor speed.
Is there any mouse method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach to the `ValueChanged` event of the `TrackBar`, and [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553371/781792) for how to control the mouse speed.