# How can I use Python 3.3 to continuously update my MouseSpeed in Windows?

Tags: python, registry, ctypes, pywin32

I am developing a python script to drive a prototype I'm developing, and my current stumbling block is attempting to continuously write to the MouseSensitivity register in Windows. I'm using Windows 7, for specificity.

Unfortunately, I've hit some dead ends.

I've attempted to use pywin32 to write to the registry, but have not succeeded. After some searching, I've come across the SystemParametersInfo Function, but have not had any success with that either.

Essentially, for the purpose of solving this crisis, I've installed pyserial, pywin32, and ctypes (it appears that pywin32 may not be required). Assume I have an integer variable that will be between (and including) 1 to 20.

What I have for code right now is listed below. Much of it has been modified from [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/jaraco.windows/2.2.1/jaraco.windows.xmouse/), as it appears that the author was using python, ctypes, user32.dll, and the SystemParametersInfo Function. However, when I run the code below, the shell enters a loop where the next line gets two tabs of space, and the cursor sits blinking until I keyboard interrupt. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

num = 12 # Between 1 and 20

SystemParametersInfo = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW

SystemParametersInfo.argtypes = (
    ctypes.wintypes.UINT,
    ctypes.wintypes.UINT,
    ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.wintypes.UINT,
    )

SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, ctypes.cast(num, ctypes.c_void_p, 0)
```

Comment: Maybe this answer could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553314/programatically-change-cursor-speed-in-windows maybe there's a way to access the same api from pywin32. I'm not on windows and have never used pywin32 so this is just a suggestion